# SQL Server 2008 R2 - Select Master and Detail Data By Conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Master and Detail Table like below and need to generate a report. The main idea is to pick Code with unique value within each Master_ID group and merge this Code with Master's ID and Revenue.

How do I use SQL to achieve this. Thank you!

```
Master
ID      Revenue
A       100
B       200
C       300
D       400
E       500
F       600

Detail      
Master_ID   No  Code
A           1   code123
A           2   N/A
B           1   N/A
C           1   code456
C           2   code789
C           3   N/A
D           1   N/A
E           1   code321
E           2   code321

Report      
No  Revenue Code
A   100     code123
B   200     N/A
C   300     N/A
D   400     N/A
E   500     code321
F   600     N/A
```

Comment: Why is result for C "N/A"?

Comment: because C's detail has 2 different code (code456 and code789). by the spec, we will ignore this case and treat it as N/A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select master_id mid, count(distinct code) dc
 from details 
 where code <> 'N/A'
 group by master_id),

filtered as
(select d.master_id fid, 
 case when c.dc = 1 then d.code else 'N/A' end fcode, 
 row_number() over (partition by d.master_id order by d.master_id) rn 
from details d
left join cte c on c.mid = d.master_id)

select m.id, m.revenue,isnull(f.fcode,'N/A') from 
master m 
left outer join filtered f
on m.id = f.fid
where isnull(f.rn,1) = 1
```

Comment: I'm so grateful! It really enlightens me. I'm not familiar CTE so would try to implement by #temp table.

Comment: Do try to learn about CTE since it can be quite convenient. But temp table ia a good idea when your subquery will retrieve a large amount of data.

Comment: BTW you might want to show your effort when you ask a question the next time. And remember to mark an answer as accepted if it helps you.

Comment: noted, next time I'll post my dirty SQL script for your reference. thanks for your advice.